# How to round a floating-point value accurately in DolphinDB?

Tags: rounding, precision, floating-accuracy, dolphindb

I want to round a float with `round` function, but the result is not what I expect. For example, the result of round(17.955, 2) is 17.95 instead of 17.96. To get the latter one, I have to add 0.0001. Why is that and How can I do?

Comment: there's no way to represent 17.95 in binary floating point. The closest is 17.9499999999999992895 [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/995714). And for values that's exactly representable then you also need to take care about things such as rounding up or rounding to nearest even for values ending with digit 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider the precision of floating points. 17.955 can only be saved as 17.954999999999998 in binary, so `round()` returns 17.95. You can convert 17.955 to DECIMAL type before using `round`, like `round(19.955$DECIMAL32(3), 2 )`